# Passing image from picturebox to rdlc report

Tags: c#, report, rdlc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUT1J.png) ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
byte[] imageBytes = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(pictureBox_qr.Image, typeof(byte[]));

```
            // Save image to a temporary file
            string tempFilePath = Path.GetTempFileName();
            File.WriteAllBytes(tempFilePath, imageBytes);

            reportViewer1.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
            // Pass temporary file path to the report
            ReportParameter imageParameter = new ReportParameter("pic_qrcode", tempFilePath);
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { imageParameter });
            
           // reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { imageParameter });

            // Refresh and display the report
            reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

i can't show the actual image from pictureBox_qr.Image to rdlc report only X image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVQXa.png)

show the actual image from pictureBox_qr.Image to rdlc report.